# How do I check if a file is text file in linux?

Tags: linux, shell

What I have to write in if command (shell programming, linux) to check if a parameter is a text file or not?
I tried with if [ -f $1 ] line, but it does not work for only text files (it gets true for every file).

Comment: First you have to define what a text file is.

Comment: Try running `file SomeFile` to test what `SomeFile` contains, e.g. `file /bin/bash` or `file image.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `if [ -f $1 ]` just checks whether or not the file exists, it does not distinguish text files or other files.

As mentioned in the comments, you might use the `file` command for that, but the output might be dependent of the Linux version you're working with, I even believe the output to be configurable. Therefore, try to launch `file SomeFile` (which gives `SomeFile: ASCII text` in case of a textfile in my case).